# Phrase removal script is removing all characters in the phrase given

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, input, raw-input

I made a python script that is supposed to automate removing a phrase from a specified text file. The problem is it's not just removing the phrase. Its removing the letters the phrase includes as well.

**Example**

Below is a test file. I'm going remove every instance of the word "python" in it with my script.

[image: Screenshot of file to clean]

Now I'll run my script.

[image: Screenshot of script being ran.]

Let's take a look at the output file.

[image: Screenshot of "cleaned" file]

**Script Code**

```
infile = input('Enter your file location: ')
outfile = "cleaned"

delete_list = input("What phrase would you like to remove from your file? ")
fin = open(infile)
fout = open(outfile, "w+")
for line in fin:
    for word in delete_list:
        line = line.replace(word, "")
    fout.write(line)
fin.close()
fout.close()
```

What is causing this? Thanks for any help in advance :)

*P.S I'm running Python 3*

Comment: `for word in delete_list` is looping over each _character_ in the phrase, not each _word_.  Try `for word in delete_list.split():` instead.

Comment: [Please post text as text not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @JohnGordon Just curious, why do you post answers in the comments? I've seen a lot of people do this.

Comment: @TheTesseract'sShadow usually I just have suggestions, not a fully fleshed-out answer, so I've gotten used to commenting.

Comment: For some reasons, it also irritates me @TheTesseract'sShadow

Answer (score 1):

Just add .split() at the input line. This makes you get a list of the input words to iterate on and delete.

```
delete_list = input("What phrase would you like to remove from your file? ").split()
```

Answer (score 0):

@JohnGordon in the comment already gave the right answer, but here is just a little easier example:

```
infile = input('Enter your file location: ')
outfile = "cleaned"
delete_list = input("What phrase would you like to remove from your file? ").split()
with open(infile,'r') as f,open(outfile,'w') as f2:
   a=f.read()
   for i in delete_list:
      a=a.replace(i,'')
   f2.write(a)
```